# How do I efficiently and specifically say that an item from a waiting list has been approved?

Tags: phrase-requests

The title of the question illustrates my point. "Approved" is not really a clear definition of what I am attempting to say. Imagine a booking system. If a user requests to book an entity on a given time, this might be impossible due to already existing bookings. The user can put his booking on a waiting list, as there is a chance the original booking might be changed, or cancelled.

In case of this, the user should get an e-mail, where it says that the booking he or her tried to make, but had to put on a waiting list, now is not any longer on the waiting list, but it is in fact a valid confirmed booking. There is no payment relevant to the bookings in my case.

I tried:

> Another booking has been updated or deleted, so that your booking is
>   now removed from the waiting list, and confirmed.

Most people will understand this just fine, but i have a feeling that "confirmed" can be ambigous. A booking can also be confirmed on a waiting list, without actually being... valid? I am missing a word here. Any other wordings I come up with, are embarrasingly long, and sounds like I'm talking to a 4-year old. Too verbose, without actually being clear...

Comment: "The conflict with another booking has been resolved and your booking has succeeded. We confirm your reservation and look forward to seeing you."

Comment: Maybe the way to go is to not call a booking a booking unless it has been confirmed. Unconfirmed bookings might be called booking requests or something along those lines. So, a user would request a booking; if that booking is available, the request would be confirmed. If existing bookings preclude that booking, then the booking request would remain pending or waitlisted. Perhaps?

Comment: If you feel that "confirmed" may be ambiguous, you may use **guaranteed** instead.

Comment: Hehe, Nice one in some cases, @AndrewLeach, but this system is for conference rooms at my company, and the bookings are for empty rooms. Otherwise I like it.

Comment: I like the  part about "booking request". That might be my real problem. The definition of booking might actually be why I find this so hard. I'm gonna try to write something on that. Thanks @jyc23

Comment: @K "The conflict with another booking has been resolved and your request has succeeded. We confirm your reservation and will send an evaluation form once you have used the room."

Comment: @MarvMills, of course a booking is not confirmed (in my mind, or in the database) until conflicts has been resolved. I just dn't feel confident that I had explained it in a good way, and that others could misinterpret it.

Comment: How about this: "Your booking request from the waiting list has become available, and is now registered as a confirmed booking"

Comment: Along the lines of @jyc23 's good suggestions, I question whether "A booking can also be **confirmed** on a waiting list, without actually being... valid?" I think that such a pending/waitlisted booking [request] can be "acknowledged," but, imo, the only thing that can/should be "confirmed" is the **receipt** of such a booking request.

Comment: @MarvMills, Yeah, you're right. My original text still seemed unprofessional in a way, and I would really like a professional, clear, simple statement.

Comment: Time for an answer, I think. This comment thread is long enough.

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue of Status and your confusion arises because you have said that a Booking can have the status of Confirmed when it is placed into the pending queue. By definition, surely a Booking *cannot* have the status of Confirmed when it is, in fact, Queued or Pending. Decide on what your valid statuses are and then use the emails to communicate status changes.

If you use the right terminology, the right Status "names" for each stage, it will be understood because it is a common enough situation. "Approved", for example, would not be a good name because it implies a separate actor that considers the request and grants or denies it (Approves or Rejects it). That is not the case here, a Pending request is merely blocked until circumstances change (the slot becomes free) whereupon it is a Confirmed booking.

So for example:

> **Booking is requested but no resource available:**
>
> "Your booking request is queued awaiting a free slot/resource/room/thing"
>
> or
>
> "Your booking request is pending/awaiting a free [whatever]"

> **Booking is subsequently made:**
>
> "Your booking has been confirmed"